# (Python module serial) No module named utilities.compatibility

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to build the PiPhone ^1, but when I execute python piphone.py, I receive the following:

I cannot seem to find anyone else who has experienced this problem. What are ways you all suggest I resolve this?

1. https://github.com/climberhunt/PiPhone

I've used `pip uninstall serial` but I haven't gotten very far solution-wise.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/serial/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import utilities, abc, model, marshal, errors, 
properties, meta, hooks, test, request
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/serial/model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utilities.compatibility import backport, 
BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_IMPORTS
ImportError: No module named utilities.compatibility
```

Comment: Exactly what `serial` package did you install? I don't see any instructions on the PiPhone page telling you what to install, but what you have now is not the [`pyserial` project](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/), which is what I'd expect the dependency to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed the wrong package. You have installed [`serial`](https://pypi.org/project/serial/), which is a Python package to handle object serialisation and deserialisation from and to YAML, JSON and XML and appears to be broken at the moment (I don't think the author is all that experienced in Python package development yet). Someone else [already filed an issue with the package to have it renamed](https://bitbucket.org/davebelais/serial/issues/2/namespace-conflict).

You want to install [`pyserial`](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) instead, which is a library to handle serial port connections.